# xyzMiddle—I don't think I'm missing anything, so what does this error mean?

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, boolean

> Given a string, does "xyz" appear in the middle of the string? To define middle, we'll say that the number of chars to the left and right of the "xyz" must differ by at most one.

Here is my take to this exercise:

```js
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
  int indexXYZ = str.indexOf("xyz");
  int toLeft = indexXYZ;
  int toRight = str.length() - (indexXYZ + 3);
  int val = toRight - toLeft;
  if(Math.abs(val) <= 1))
    return true;
  else return false;
}
```

I am not sure why, but I keep on getting a compile error message that says "missing '}' or illegal start of expression", but I don't think I'm missing anything. Could someone please help me figure out my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean xyzMiddle(String str) {
    int indexXYZ = str.indexOf("xyz");
    int toLeft = indexXYZ;
    int toRight = str.length() - (indexXYZ + 3);
    int val = toRight - toLeft;
    if(Math.abs(val) <= 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

You had a structural error in the if section